# Getting the right seasonality PDQ for SARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-selection, seasonality

I am a bit confused about how to identify the seasonal component of a SARIMA model. I am currently looking at forecasting rates (ocean carrier rates to be specific). The first thing I did was to convert my original rates to the difference in rates, i.e. log(P2) - log(P1) as I wanted to forecast the change in rate itself. Then I checked for stationarity of the series and it was stationary. This is what the seasonal decomposed series look like:

[image]

After that, I ran a basic ARIMA model and chose the p,d,q based on the ACF and PACF plots here

[image]

but the predictions didn't follow the seasonality which was expected:

[image]

I am now trying to run a SARIMA model instead. I obtained the seasonality component via seasonal_decompose and plotted the ACF and PACF over seasonally differenced data (i have weekly data) and this is what I see
[image: see]

How do I choose the right pdq component for SARIMA?

Comment: First, the predictions are not necessarily bad. Second, your last plot does not tell us enough about the seasonal lag orders. You need some 520 lags rather than 52 for that.

Comment: I have added a new ACF and PACF graph that I got from seasonally differencing the series instead.

Comment: Why did you apply seasonal differencing? Did you find a seasonal unit root in your data?

Comment: I applied a seasonal differencing because of 2 reasons: i. Business intuition was that there is a yearly seasonal component to the data. ii. The seasonal component from the seasonal_decompose function yielded a clear yearly seasonal trend. Hence, I figured SARIMA would be a better option to predict the model. In order to find the P,D,Q component for SARIMA, I then applied seasonal differencing to look at the ACF and PACF graphs. Is that an incorrect way of doing it?

Comment: Seasonal differencing is warranted if the time series has a seasonal unit root. A mere presence of a seasonal pattern, however pronounced, is no indication that seasonal differencing is appropriate.

Comment: Just to clarify, I only did the seasonal differencing to identify the PDQ terms in the SARIMA model. The target variable itself is not seasonal differenced. I only took the first difference to make the time series stationary. Is that appropriate? If not what is a better way to identify the PDQ of the SARIMA model.

Comment: How are you going to identify the D term if you have seasonally differenced your data? That implies D$\geq$1 without allowing for D=0. Regarding a modern approach to SARIMA model selection, check out the `auto.arima` algorithm available in the `forecast` package in R. (There is an equivalent in Python, too.)

Comment: what is a common way to test for seasonal unit root?

Comment: See [this document](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.16/topics/nsdiffs). The default option described there is a good starting point.